# Pytorch CPU OOM kills ssh server on linux

Tags: pytorch, cpu, ram, oom

I've run into a problem that pytorch (tested with 2.0.1+cu117) does not fail gracefully when CPU OOM occurs. Specifically, I lose all ssh connections and Xserver access to the VM or bare metal machine.

I've not tested if this occurs on any other os.

the only solution I've found is to directly reboot the machine (through vsphere or just a power button).

I've considered aliasing python (accounting for conda env switching) to add each process to a cgroup which directly limits memory usage, but I've been advised that messing with cgroups is broadly a bad idea.

It is hard to judge how much memory a model is going to take, and I need a graceful way to kill it without it killing my ssh-server.

Some notes:
I've tried this on two devices one VM one bare metal, both are Ubuntu 22.04, and I believe both have the OS-level OOM killer enabled. This is not reproducible with GPU OOM as that will actually kill the process and returns a typical GPU OOM error, but rather only with RAM.

I've tried setting the RLIMIT as described here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-how-to-put-limits-on-memory-and-cpu-usage/. Though that hasn't solved my problem.

I've also considered just adding a condition in my training that checks available memory and breaks, but this seems like a unclean solution.

I haven't tried cgroups because as above mentioned. I'm also only tangentially familiar with OS things and I hesitate to do anything with it lest I break something I cannot fix.

Comment: TLDR: [Disable the OOM killer](https://lwn.net/Articles/104185/): "An aircraft company discovered that it was cheaper to fly its planes
with less fuel on board. The planes would be lighter and use less fuel
and money was saved. On rare occasions however the amount of fuel was
insufficient, and the plane would crash. This problem was solved by
the engineers of the company by the development of a special OOF
(out-of-fuel) mechanism. In emergency cases a passenger was selected
and thrown out of the plane." It's impossible to have a reliable system when processes can get killed like that.

Comment: Disabling the OOM killer would probably prevent the SSH-server from dying, but it doesn't solve the overall problem. "the plane still crashes" so the ssh-server would still crash, but just because the machine crashed rather than the ssh-server being ejected.

Comment: No, it won't crash.  As long as you put enough "fuel on the plane" (enough memory...) disabling the OOM killer and memory overcommit means that processes won't be able to request memory and then cause the killing of *other* processes that are critical to system reliability.  You'll just wind up with a system that, instead of **lying** to a process about how much memory it can use, will tell them up front they can't have that much memory.  In other words, a reliable system.

Comment: You **can not** build a reliable system of any type based on inaccurate information, and Linux's use of memory overcommit means processes have inaccurate information about available memory.  It's difficult to be more fundamentally unreliable than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-how-to-put-limits-on-memory-and-cpu-usage/

^ I implemented this incorrectly prior (misspelling on the restricted attribute), but this in fact does solve the problem and prevents overuse of RAM.

https://github.com/daniel-redder/mem_restrict/blob/main/mem_restrict.py
^ import to constrain

```
import psutil
import resource


#https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-how-to-put-limits-on-memory-and-cpu-usage/

PERCENTAGE_MEMORY_ALLOWED = 0.8

# Calculate the maximum memory limit (80% of available memory)
virtual_memory = psutil.virtual_memory()
available_memory = virtual_memory.available
memory_limit = int(available_memory * PERCENTAGE_MEMORY_ALLOWED)

print(f'{memory_limit} memory limit, available: {available_memory}')

# Set the memory limit
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (memory_limit, memory_limit))
```

(I will continue discussing the OOM killer stuff here because it is interesting, but I want to put up the easy solution)

Comment: Sounds like a good solution. Please also add the most important keywords or a small code snippet directly into the answer. Links can go dead, and answers [should be useful standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try tuning `oom_score_adj` using the `choom` command:

```bash
choom -n 1000 -- python yourscript.py
```

Quoting `man proc` about `/proc/<pid>/oom_score_adj`:

> [..] adjust the badness heuristic used to select which process gets killed in out-of-memory conditions. [The badness value is] ranging  from  0 (never kill) to 1000 (always kill) to determine which process is targeted.

If you are not sure if the OOM killer was active, you can check what happened in the kernel log with `journalctl -ke`. (If you had to reboot, add `--boot -1`.) It will look like this:

*Out of memory: Killed process 68412 (python3) total-vm:70398288kB, anon-rss:61052944kB, file-rss:2304kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:119712kB oom_score_adj:1000*

Further reading:

- [More about oom_score_adj](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/666075/196595) (unix.stackexchange.com)
- [Linux Memory Overcommitment and the OOM Killer](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/memory-overcommitment-oom-killer) (baeldung.com)

Comment: I'm giving this a try. There are some program specific things I can do to monitor and manage RAM obviously, but what I am looking for is something like this a way to ensure the python script is killed before the ssh-server without regard for what the python script is.

I will update this comment with my results after applying this.

Comment: Actually my sshd has an oom_score_adj of -1000, meaning it should never get killed. Maybe your problem is actually that your system is swapping and not doing much else. Check your swap setup with `cat /proc/swaps`. Maybe you have too much swap or are swapping to a very slow disk. Maybe try `swapoff -a`.

Comment: cat /proc/swaps 
/swapfile                               file            2097148         0               -2

Comment: 2GB swap sounds reasonable. It's useful to keep programs that never run away from RAM. Still, if you read more RAM than you have in a loop, swapping may slow down your system so much that it looks like it crashed.