# Storing neural network forwarded states in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am implementing [1] model on Google Colaboratory with Pytorch in which I need to store multiple states of forward passes for later loss and back-propagation computations. To do this, I stored the resulting tensors into a Python list.

However, I later discovered that this approach would pose memory leaks since the entire computational graph is copied onto the list [2], leading to a huge amount of GPU RAM be used up. I can not do anything after a few tensors are passed through the network.

I did found a solution on Pytorch forum [3] that uses torch.utils.checkpoint, but I am not satisfied. Why Pytorch does not provide any means to store list of references to tensors, instead of forcing everything to be copied?

[1] https://www.crcv.ucf.edu/projects/real-world/ 
[2] https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/correct-way-storing-states-inside-one-forwardpass/46868 
[3] https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/memory-when-storing-states-in-a-list/63012/2

The part of my code for reference, notice I commented out the `append` method and observe a huge memory saved. I added `break` for debugging.

```
    """ Run 01 epoch of training
    """
    def fit_epoch(self):
        epoch_training_loss = []

        for batch_idx, (normal_bag, abnormal_bag) in enumerate(self._DATALOADER):
            self._OPTIM.zero_grad()
            self._MODEL.train()

            normal_scores = []
            for idx, segment in enumerate(normal_bag):
                segment = segment.type(torch.FloatTensor).to(device)
                score = self._MODEL.forward(segment)
                # normal_scores.append(score)

                del segment, score

                # Lookout memory leaks
                # https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/memory-leak-when-appending-tensors-to-a-list/25937/3

            abnormal_scores = []
            for idx, segment in enumerate(abnormal_bag):
                segment = segment.type(torch.FloatTensor).to(device)
                score = self._MODEL.forward(segment)
                # abnormal_scores.append(score)

                del segment, score

            break

            # Compute loss
            loss = self._LOSS_FN(normal_scores, abnormal_scores)

            # Back-propagation
            loss.backward()
            self._OPTIM.step()

            epoch_training_loss.append(loss.item())

        self._save_model()
        return epoch_training_loss
```

[image: GPU piles up]

Answer (score 0):

*"Why Pytorch does not provide any means to store list of references to tensors, instead of forcing everything to be copied?"*

I don't see a answer to this question in pytorch docs, but this question is irrelevant to this post. I say this because, when you comment out `# abnormal_scores.append(score)` it removes the only reference to the score for the next iteration. **This allows for garbage collecting to remove that score's computational graph, this is why you see the lower memory usage.**

This section of the model: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRt6J.png) where you are comparing different scores is what is causing this overhead not the way you are storing the tensor.

You have three possibilities:

**-- Gradient accumulation:** broadly in models you could accumulate the gradients and divide by the sum rather than backpropagating across the aggregate, because **a sum of gradients = a gradient of sums**. Now this doesn't apply directly in this case because you are doing comparisons rather than summation, one option is you could sample from a distribution of the scores rather than maintaining a record of all of them  this would allow for lower overhead (storing fewer computational graphs).

**-- Smaller batches**: somewhat self explanatory, you can use smaller batch sizes, or in this case fewer comparisons at a time

**-- CPU Memory / Storage** You can move those tensors to CPU as you append them offloading the gpu memory strain to the RAM, but beware [Pytorch CPU OOM kills ssh server on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77403056/pytorch-cpu-oom-kills-ssh-server-on-linux?noredirect=1#comment136456461_77403056) (this doesn't apply on colab, but any linux server)

**Regarding the pytorch references question, I will continue to look for a reference and edit this if I find something that isn't just a guess**